# Efficient Way to Aggregate and Construct Matrix out of User Product Data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data in the form of csv/pandas that looks like this:

[image]

I want to aggregate the user product data into a matrix like this.

[image]

How can I do this efficiently? Efficiency is really important.

Comment: go check `pandas.pivot_table`

Answer (score 1):

I can't add comments yet so here's my answer instead:
you can simply pivot the table.

```
# df <- dataframe
df.pivot(index='User', columns='Product', values='Cost').fillna(0)
```